# Reducing size of a block diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, block

I have a drawn a block diagram with the following code. However I want to reduce its size to around 70 %. How can I do that.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}
%\usepackage{adjustbox}% <--- not needed
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                chains,% <--- new
                decorations.markings,
                shadows, shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{% <--- modified
    decision/.style = {diamond,draw, fill=blue!50},
        line/.style = {draw, -stealth, thick},
       block/.style = {rectangle, draw,  text width=4 em, minimum height=10 mm,
                       align=center}
        }
\makeatletter
\tikzset{suspend join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}              
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
          node distance = 0ex and 3em,
          start chain = A going right,
          every join/.style = {draw, -stealth, thick},
          block/.append style = {on chain=A, join}
                        ]
\node [block]   {A};% <-- A-1
\node [block,right=5em of A-1]    {B};
\node [block]   {C};
\node [block]   {D};
\node [block]   {E};% <-- A-5
\node [block,suspend join]  {Accom\-modating Text
                             inside a block needed};
\node [single arrow, draw=red, minimum height=3em, outer sep=0pt,
       right=0pt of A-5.east] {\vphantom{x}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you could use the package `tikzscale` and `\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{file.tikz}`. Then the text size stays the same (which looks better, but might become problematic inside the boxes)

Comment: How can I get .tikz file. I tried to save the file as sys.tikz but texmaker saves it as sys.tikz.tex, which is not recognized by \includegraphics command

Comment: Then you should just rename it to sys.tikz ;) Only certain files, like .pdf, .png are recognized by `\includegraphics`. With `\usepackage{tikzscale}` it's also possible for .tikz Inside the file, you just put the `tikzpicture`-environment

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

The following defines a macro `\blocktext`, which uses environment `varwidth` of package `varwidth` to limit the width to `4em`, but allowing the width to shrink, if the full width is not needed:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                chains,% <--- new
                decorations.markings,
                shadows, shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{%
    decision/.style = {diamond,draw, fill=blue!50},
        line/.style = {draw, -stealth, thick},
       block/.style = {rectangle, draw, minimum height=10mm,
                       align=center}
        }
\makeatletter
\tikzset{suspend join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\blocktext}[1]{%
  \begin{varwidth}{4em}%
    \centering
    #1%
  \end{varwidth}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
          node distance = 0ex and 3em,
          start chain = A going right,
          every join/.style = {draw, -stealth, thick},
          block/.append style = {on chain=A, join}
                        ]
\node [block] {\blocktext{A}};
\node [block] {\blocktext{B}};
\node [block] {\blocktext{C}};
\node [block] {\blocktext{D}};
\node [block] {\blocktext{E}};
\node [block,suspend join]  {\blocktext{Accom\-modating Text
                             inside a block needed}};
\node [single arrow, draw=red, minimum height=3em, outer sep=0pt,
       right=0pt of A-5.east] {\vphantom{x}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]