# How to draw the diamond structure using `chains`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

I am using `chains` to re-draw the structure (shown below) in [Second isomorphism theorem(wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Second_isomorphism_theorem).
[image: 2nd-iso-wiki]

The code and the resulting figure is shown as follows.

How to get rid of the dummy node (added for alignment) and the unnecessary `join` lines between it and the node `hn` and `hcapn`, respectively?

[image: 2nd-iso]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, scopes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every on chain/.style = join, every join/.style = -, node distance = 0.8cm and 1.0cm]
  { 
    [start chain = G going below] % G chain
    \node (g) [on chain] {$G$};
    \node (hn) [on chain, below = 0.50cm of g] {$HN$}; 
    { [start branch = H going below left] % H branch
      \node (h) [on chain] {$H$};
    }
    { [start branch = N going below right] % N branch
      \node [on chain] {$N$};
    }
    \node [on chain] {}; % dummy node % continue G chain
    \node (hcapn) [on chain, join = with G/H-end, join = with G/N-end] {$H \cap N$};
    \node (e) [on chain, below = 0.50cm of hcapn] {$\{ e \}$};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with chain, but two nodes are excluded in join macro and for it the connection is drawn separately:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, shapes.geometric}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{suspend join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 10 mm,
  start chain = going below,
     N/.style = {ellipse, draw, inner sep=2pt, on chain, join=by -}]
\node (g)       [N] {$G$};
\node (hn)      [N] {$HN$};
\node (h)       [N, below left=of hn]   {$H$};
\node (hcapn)   [N, below=of h -| hn]   {$H \cap N$};
\node (e)       [N] {$\{ e \}$};
%
\node (n)       [N,suspend join,
                 below right=of hn]     {$N$};
\node [below=of hn] {$\cong$};
\draw (hn) -- (n)   (n) -- (hcapn);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is it that an identical definition of `suspend join` can be found e.g. in [Heiko Oberdiek's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304568/121799)?

Comment: i didn't invent this definition. i obtained it from some Ulrike Fisher answer (many) years ago. what you like to tel me with your comment?

Comment: What I want to say is: imagine you had invented this definition, and someone else, let's say I, would use it to answer a question that reads "How to get rid of the dummy node (added for alignment) and the unnecessary join lines between it and the node hn and hcapn, respectively?". Wouldn't you like it much better if the other user, let's say I, would say "I am going to use a definition invented by Zarko..." better?

Comment: @marmot, no, i'm not sensitive to do this. and on the another hand, to give credits to all where i find some interesting solution is almost impossible. how do i should remember all  answers which i read (few thousands till now) ? i store in my latex corner only some of attractive (to me) solutions, but my evidence, where i find them is very poor :-(. best regards!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to replicate the linked picture, I propose this

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.75cm,y=1.75cm]
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=1cm}]
\node (g) at (0,2) {$G$};
\node (sn) at (0,1) {$SN$};
\node (n) at (-1,0) {$N$};
\node (s) at (1,0) {$S$};
\node[ellipse,draw,minimum height=1cm] (scn) at (0,-1) {$S\cap N$};
\node (e) at (0,-2) {$\{e\}$};
\end{scope}
\draw (g)--(sn)--(n)--(scn)--(e) (scn)--(s)--(sn);
\node[rotate=-45,ellipse,draw,dashed,inner xsep=-7mm,inner ysep=-1mm,fit=(sn)(n)] {};
\node[rotate=-45,ellipse,draw,dashed,inner xsep=-9mm,inner ysep=1mm,fit=(scn)(s)] {};
\node {$\cong$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]