# Rotate arrow in tikz

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

How can I rotate arrow to block in the upper right corner? I need the arrow follows between blocks.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    \node [block] (step1) {Elimination of redundant information using PCA};
    \node [block, below of = step1] (step2) {Transition to integral characteristics for time intervals by means of discrete wavelet transform};
    \node [block, below of = step2] (step3) {Computing the mutual distance matrix between subjects};
    \node [block, below of = step3] (step4) {Applying multidimensional scaling to analyze the mutual allocation of subjects within a space with acceptable dimensions};
    \node [block, below of = step4] (step5) {Cluster analysis of subjects in the obtained scaling space};
    \node [block, right of = step1, xshift=5cm] (step6) {Computing the mutual distance matrix between subjects};
    \node [block, below of = step6] (step7) {Probabilistic assessments of subject class recognition using sample distribution functions of distances to cluster centers.};
    \node [block, below of = step7] (step8) {Selecting the subject class or the closest subjects from different classes, with difference parameters being calculated};
    \node [block, below of = step8] (step9) {Clarifying the relationship to the classes under consideration.};

    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (step1) -- (step2);
    \path [line] (step2) -- (step3);
    \path [line] (step3) -- (step4);
    \path [line] (step4) -- (step5);

    \draw [line, thick] (step5.south) |-+(0,-1em)-||- ([xshift=-.6cm]step6.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fragment leaves many things undefined (`block`, `line`) and uses a deprecated way of positioning nodes. I had to make up styles, and could imagine you are looking for something like this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304563
\makeatletter
\tikzset{suspend join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance =1cm and 1.2cm, auto,block/.style={draw, rectangle, 
    minimum height=7em,text width=12em,rounded
    corners,fill=blue!20,font=\sffamily,on chain=step},
    line/.style={thick,-stealth,draw},
    start chain=step going below,
    nodes={block,join=by {line}}]
    \node   {Elimination of redundant information using PCA};
    \node   {Transition to integral characteristics for time intervals by means of discrete wavelet transform};
    \node   {Computing the mutual distance matrix between subjects};
    \node   {Applying multidimensional scaling to analyze the mutual allocation of subjects within a space with acceptable dimensions};
    \node   {Cluster analysis of subjects in the obtained scaling space};
    \node[right=of step-1,suspend join]   {Computing the mutual distance matrix between subjects};
    \node   {Probabilistic assessments of subject class recognition using sample distribution functions of distances to cluster centers.};
    \node   {Selecting the subject class or the closest subjects from different classes, with difference parameters being calculated};
    \node   {Clarifying the relationship to the classes under consideration.};
    \path[line, thick] (step-5.south) --+(0,-1em)-| ([xshift=-.6cm]step-6.west)
        -- (step-6.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I should learn correct ways of positioning nodes.

Comment: @PavelD You are welcome! If you position them by hand, please use the `positioning` library. The above setup can also be achieved with a `matrix of nodes` from the `matrix` library.