# How do I make these changes in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I have created this squence using a reference code that was answered in my previous question. I'm new to tikz and don't really know how to use it. When I try to delete the nodes with the ducks, the entire code breaks. I want the second image to directly connect with the node array of 4. Also, the arrows also seem to be messed up in the array of 4 images. Could someone help me out and explain how to make changes here?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[arj/.style={-latex}] 
\begin{scope}[start chain=R going right,
    nodes={on chain,join=by arj}]
 \path node{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{405615.jpg}}
  node{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{centre_crop.jpg}}
  node[scale=0.8]{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-duck}}
  node{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-duck}}
  [arj/.append style={opacity=0}]
  node[opacity=0]{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-duck}}
  node[opacity=0]{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-duck}}
  [arj/.append style={opacity=1}]
  node[opacity=1]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{flipping.jpg}}
  ;
\end{scope} 
\path (R-5) node[matrix] {
    \node(R-5-1){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{rotate_1.jpg}};\\
    \node(R-5-2){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{rotate_2.jpg}};\\
   \node(R-5-3){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{rotate_3.jpg}};\\
   \node(R-5-4){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{rotate_4.jpg}};\\}
   (R-6) node[matrix] {\node[xscale=-1](R-6-1){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{height_shift.jpg}};\\
   \node[yscale=-1](R-6-2){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{width_shift.jpg}};\\};
\path[arj] (R-4.east) foreach \X in {1,...,4} { edge (R-5-\X.270-90*\X)}   
(R-5.east) foreach \X in {1,2} { edge (R-6-\X.180-180*\X)};   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also want to add captions under each image in here, how do I do that? And what is `arj./style`?

The resulting image should be similar to this one, except with less nodes and the captions should be visible.
[image]

Comment: `arj/.style={-latex}` and most likely others won't have your graphics files to compile this code.

Comment: But if I try to remove the nodes with the ducks, the entire code breaks. How do I fix that? Could others use a sample image to compile?

Comment: You can use `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm,demo]{standalone}`, then others won't have the problem with the graphics files. Can you please explain what "removing the ducks" means? If I take them out, the resulting sequence will have two nodes less than the target picture.

Comment: Yes, I want to remove those nodes with the ducks and connect the second node to the 5th one, which is an array of 4 images. The resulting sequence should have only 5 nodes.

Comment: While the TikZ manual is rather large, the section on chains (pp 602-608) isn't.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why your code is allergic to removing nodes is that a `chain` is used, which auto-numbers the nodes. However, two entries of the chain are dummy entries that get replaced by matrices. These entries have specific numbers on the chain. More precisely, since we say `start chain=R` the names of the nodes will be `R-1`, `R-2` and so on. So if you remove some nodes before the matrices, you need to change the indices of the matrices. I have changed this in this code and store the positions in the macros `\matindexA` and `\matindexB`. In this code, adding some caption under the nodes is as simple as saying `pp=<caption>`. `pp` uses a `label`, which you can also use to add captions to the matrices.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm,demo]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\makeatletter% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304563
\tikzset{suspend join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[arj/.style={-latex}] 
\begin{scope}[start chain=R going right,
    pp/.style={on chain,join=by arj,label=below:{#1}}]
 \path node[pp=blub]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{405615.jpg}}
  node[pp=foo]{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{centre_crop.jpg}}
  [arj/.append style={opacity=0}]
  node[pp,minimum width=2cm]{}
  node[pp,minimum width=2cm]{}  
  [arj/.append style={opacity=1}]
  node[pp=bar,opacity=1]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{flipping.jpg}}
  ;
\end{scope} 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\matindexA}{3}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\matindexB}{4}
\path (R-\matindexA) node[matrix,label=below:abc] {
    \node(R-\matindexA-1){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{rotate_1.jpg}};\\
    \node(R-\matindexA-2){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{rotate_2.jpg}};\\
   \node(R-\matindexA-3){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{rotate_3.jpg}};\\
   \node(R-\matindexA-4){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{rotate_4.jpg}};\\}
   (R-\matindexB) node[matrix,label=below:xyz] {\node[xscale=-1](R-\matindexB-1){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{height_shift.jpg}};\\
   \node[yscale=-1](R-\matindexB-2){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{width_shift.jpg}};\\};
\path[arj] (R-\the\numexpr\matindexA-1\relax.east) foreach \X in {1,...,4} { edge (R-\matindexA-\X.west)}   
 (R-\matindexA.east) foreach \X in {1,2} { edge (R-\matindexB-\X)};   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it's not reading my input images now and showing all black :(

Comment: @Madara You need to remove `demo` from `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm,demo]{standalone}` to get `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}`.